# PHP DateTime Difference (Hours, Days, Weeks, Months)

Tags: php, datetime, date-difference

I am creating PHP function that will return difference between two dates in a format: **2 Months, 3 Weeks, 6 Days, 3 Hours**. I have tried to use PHP DateTime class, but it returns only Months, Days and Hours and I can not find a way to calculate *Weeks*.

This is my function:

```
public function DateTimeDifference($FromDate, $ToDate) {
  $FromDate = new DateTime($FromDate);
  $ToDate   = new DateTime($ToDate);
  $Interval = $FromDate->diff($ToDate);

  $Difference["Hours"] = $Interval->h;
  $Difference["Days"] = $Interval->d;
  $Difference["Months"] = $Interval->m;

  return $Difference;
}
```

Now, I need $Difference["Weeks"] also included in return data.

EDIT: I know I can divide Days with 7 and get weeks, but this does not result right. For example: **2 Months, 14 Days, 3 Hours** - When I divide **14 days** with 7 I will get this: **2 Months, 2 Weeks, 14 Days, 3 Hours** and now this is not same period.

Comment: Interesting... how many days in one week?

Comment: Interesting... how to find modulo from days divided by 7?

Comment: You don't even need to use modulo, it's simple math.

Comment: @Andreas, I heard there are some countries where computer science is taught separately from math. That's ok) but (days-weeks*7) === (days -
 floor(days/7)*7) === days%7, which is modulo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public function DateTimeDifference($FromDate, $ToDate) {
  $FromDate = new DateTime($FromDate);
  $ToDate   = new DateTime($ToDate);
  $Interval = $FromDate->diff($ToDate);

  $Difference["Hours"] = $Interval->h;
  $Difference["Weeks"] = floor($Interval->d/7);
  $Difference["Days"] = $Interval->d % 7;
  $Difference["Months"] = $Interval->m;

  return $Difference;
}
```

Comment: This is correct. Cray uses the modulo operator to calculate the remainder after division of the days by 7. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this will only work from previous dates 
// difference between utc date time and custom date time

function FromUtcToCustomDateTimeDifference($ToDate)
{
    
    // Takes Two date time
    $UTC_DATE = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $UTC_DATETIME = $UTC_DATE->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    
    // add your own date time 1
    $datetime1 = date_create(UTC_DATETIME);
    $datetime2 = date_create($ToDate);
   
    $Interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    // Count Number Of Days Difference
    
    $Day = $Interval->format('%a');
        
    if($Day > 1)
        {

            $Month = $Interval->format('%m');
            $Year = $Interval->format('%y');
            $Week = (int)($Interval->format('%a')/7);
            
            if($Year<1)
            {

                        if($Day <= 7)
                        {
                            return $Day > 1 ?  $Day.= " days ago" : $Day .= " day ago";

                        }

                        else if($Month<1)
                        {
                            
                        return $Week > 1 ?  $Week.= " weeks ago" : $Week .= " week ago";
                        }
                        
                        
                        return $Month > 1 ? $Month.= " months ago" : $Month .= " month ago";
            }
            else
            {
                return $Year > 1 ? $Year.= " years ago" : $Year .= " year ago";
                
            }

        
        }
        else
        {

            return "today";

        }
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).