# Count week between two dates in php?

Tags: php, date, datetime, datediff

I am doing weekly report excel file export. I have `$dateFrom` and `$dateTo`.

```
$dateForm = "2021-07-26";
$dateTo = "2021-08-13";
```

I want to get by week based on those two dates. **Monday to Sunday** is one week and I want to get the `dateForm` and `dateTo` for that week.

The result I want to display is:

**For example :**

```
dateForm      dateTo     
----------   ----------
2021-07-26   2021-08-01
2021-08-02   2021-08-08
2021-08-09   2021-08-13
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: With something like `date("W", strtotime($yourdate))` you can get the week of the year.

Comment: You should try to do it with dateTime diff object - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682106/php-datetime-difference-hours-days-weeks-months

Answer (score 1):

As `@KIKO Software` said in comments, You can use `date("W", strtotime($yourdate))` to get the week of the year.

**Check this code:**

```php
<?php

$startDate = "2021-07-26";
$endDate = "2021-08-26";

$numberOfWeeks = (int)date("W", strtotime($endDate)) - (int)date("W", strtotime($startDate));

echo $numberOfWeeks;

?>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and what about dates like: "2021-12-16" - "2022-02-03"?